# searching strings from a file into another file in c

Tags: c

I have a text file(names.txt) with single names like:

```
mary
john
kj
mark
```

Am trying to match them with other data in another text file(records.txt),it looks like this:

```
mary jon mik 200 west 90
fgg gh 400 east 700
james ggg 890 south 800
john nike 556 4666
```

Am reading names.txt and running the names against records.txt , if a name matches the entire line in records.txt is printed. When i feed the names one by one from CL,it is ok.But when i adapt the code to do as above from a text file , its not working.Can someone please point me to the right direction.Here is my code:

```
/*program to search for a given string from a file*/
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int usage(char*argv[]);


 int main (int argc,char*argv[])
 {
  int flag=0,i=0;
  FILE*fp,*lp;
  char line[50];
  char word[10];

  lp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  fp=fopen(argv[2],"r");

  if (argc!=3) {
     usage(argv[0]);
 exit(0);
  }

  if (lp==NULL || fp==NULL) {
 perror("can't open file");
  exit(1);
   }


  //getting words to search

  while (fgets(word,10,lp)!=NULL) {

     for(i=0;i<=strlen(word);i++){
        if(word[i]=='\n'){
          word[i]='\0';
          break;
         }
      }
    printf("searching for %s in %s ",word,argv[2]);
     //searching in file
    i=0;
    while (fgets(line,50,fp)!=NULL) {
     i++;
     if(strstr(line,word)!=NULL){
       printf("%s found in line %d\n%s.\n",word,i,line);
       flag=1;
 }   
  }
  if(flag==0)
    puts("no match found");
  flag=0;
 }
 putchar('\n');
 exit(0);

}
int usage(char*argv[])
{
  printf("usage:\n<argv> <source file> < search file>\n");
  return 0;
 }
```

Running the above code this is what am getting:

```
  searching for mary
  in records.txt
  jon mik mary 56 567

  mary found in line 1
  jon mik mary 56 56

  searching for john
  in records.txt 
  no match found
  searching for kj
  in records.txt
  no match found
  searching for mark in records.txt 
  no match found
```

Comment: Looks like you are not stripping `\n` off of the words to search for.

Comment: A bit of debugging wouldn't go amiss.  That's where you try to logically deduce what's happening by examining your values throughout execution to see whether they are what you expect them to be.  This is one of the most fundamental aspects of being a programmer.  Experimentation / trial and error / investigation.

Comment: It should be clear the flag when entering the next search.

Comment: @paddy i have tried to and my brain just fails me!

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=strlen(word);i++){` does not look kosher to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you are not stripping the white space from the end of `word` and then you are also appending a space and I am not sure why. With minimal changes if you iterate over `word` each time you read a new line and replace the first `\n` with `\0` that will fix that.

The second issue is that you are only iterating over the contents of the second file once and so you are only comparing the words in `names.txt` against the first line in `records.txt`.

You also need to reset `flag` back to `0`.

Comment: I added the space since when i was entering the name from CL it matched any sequence of the string i entered.Let me do the stripper and see.Thanks

Comment: Doing a little editing as @shafik suggested i get the above results(edited original post).Its clear as he said am not iterating the second file!I thought the two while loops are supposed to do that.How does one do it?

Comment: @wildplasser Just stripping  \n from the string. If there is a better way to do it, Am open to suggestions.